Linear Regulator Pass Transistor vs Parallel Regulators
I've been looking into using linear regulators to create a variable DC supply.
The two ways I've seen to increase the output current for linear regulators is to place multiple in parallel with small resistors between them to help load share.
Another way I've seen it done is to use a pass transistor which will do the bulk of the current.
Is one approach preferred over the other?
Is the ripple rejection similar in both setups?

Image source and reference: LT3080 datasheet

Elliott W. - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].)

@devnull - Thanks for adding the missing reference for the copied material. || Eliott W. - Hi again, Although another site member has kindly added the missing reference I mentioned in my previous comment, I won't delete these comments yet, to ensure that you see them as it is your responsibility to comply with the site referencing rule. If I delete the comments now, you might never see them and therefore might not see that explanation of your responsibility. Please reply with a brief comment when you've read this, then I'll delete it. TY

I don't like using a current booster transistor on a linear regulator.
It cancels most of the advantages of an integrated regulator. These chips usually offer thermal protection, SOA protection, current limiting and short circuit protection, all of which will not work as the regulator cannot sense the booster transistor's current and temperature.
Another advantage of the integrated regulator is simplicity, which is also lost, because it amounts to designing a feedback system while having no idea what the open loop gain is, because the open loop gain of the linear regulator in the loop is usually unspecified.
There are other issues, for example on the schematic in the question, the booster transistor has a 50 ohms resistor across its B-E junction. It forms a CFP with the pass transistor in the LT3080, but it will only turn on if the LT3080 passes more current than 0.6V/50ohms. So the system is likely to behave differently in the two regimes depending if the pass transistor is on or off. Transconductance of the booster transistor is proportional to current flowing through it, so the increase in open loop gain due to the transistor will also be proportional to current.
If I had to design a high current linear regulator, I'd use either discretes, or an opamp driving power transistors. In the first case, open loop gain and compensation are part of the design, with an opamp, open loop gain is specified.
If the linear regulator can take the current but the problem is dissipation or excessive voltage, then a pure linear solution would be to "cascode" it with a transistor. This is simpler because the cascode transistor doesn't need to form an accurate regulator, a simple follower will do. Also the regulator will usually need a rather small input cap and can tolerate a substantial amount of ESR on the input which ensures stability of the cascode. A more efficient solution is to use a switching pre-regulator followed by a LDO to clean up the ripple.

What is a "CFP"?

This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sziklai_pair

One thing that might favor one over the other is how much range you want in the output voltage.
For example the schematic with two devices paralleled shows an input range of 8 V to 28 V and an output of 3.3 V @ 2 A. But according to the datasheet page 6 the output current with a differential voltage (\$V_{in} - V_{out}\$) of 24 V is limited to somewhere around 200 mA, so you shouldn't be able to run that circuit with 28 V in and get 3.3 V @ 2 A out. For a variable supply you'll need to look at this in relation to your maximum and minimum voltage requirements, the higher you want the max, the more differential you have at the min.
With an external "wrap-around" pass transistor you could select a transistor that could handle higher current at high different voltage and keep the regulator current itself relatively low.
You'll need to evaluate the circuit requirements over the voltage and current range you want for your variable supply. It would be helpful to include your design specifications in your question as well.
Note that if you do want to parallel them there is a version LT3080-1 that doesn't require the balancing resistors.


What is Ripple Rejection?  Essentially PSRR @ 120Hz  typ.

I would include a combo of line, load regulation (Input and Output noise) and Ripple Rejection [dB].

Both are bandaid solutions for an unplanned overload.
A better solution is to use a modern linear regulator rated for your application.
e.g. Torex XC6220B331ER-G is much cheaper (< $0.50) rated for 1A and has better specs.

Input ripple could be from an SMPS but should differ for the above examples using the specs which only include DC line and 120 Hz ripple. Feedthru capacitance and GBW limits of the OpAmp will limit error correction on the output.
for the LT3060 as follows;


Load regulation is simply the ratio of output impedance to load.

Being a unipolar regulator (emitter follower) it is inherently stable with parallel drivers. ("high man wins" logic and will current limit 1st)

Push-Pull regulators in tandem are inherently unstable unless errors are nulled with a minimum 10% preload added or Rs is added which degrades load reg.

Bypassing the regulator demands the emitter resistor ratio is precisely calculated for current limiting and heatsinking of the bypass transistor with similar Tja coefficients for existing OTP and OCP functions to work.



These specs are misleading as they assume the best case input DC uses rectified 60 Hz and say 100mV of noise > 100kHz from a DIY SMPS.  They would be expected to follow the PSRR of an OA which is poor at unity gain.
e.g.
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Torex-Semiconductor/XC6220B331ER-G?qs=AsjdqWjXhJ%252BJj%252BEWI7nHIg%3D%3D
Ali $
$0.13

I prefer the single regulator with one or more boost transistors.  This way there is only one voltage reference, one control amplifier, one feedback connection, etc.  No conflicts.  Many regulators have the schematic and design equations in the datasheet or in an app note.
Also, depending on the regulator(s), the single-regulator approach can give you more control over current sharing and the power dissipation in the various devices.

That depends on the regulators, your needs in regulation accuracy and the dynamics of your load and upstream power source.
For example, your pass transistor might have a much higher gain than the control loop internally expects – which might lead to instability, and at the very least requires you to pick the controlling resistor carefully, potentially also to compensate a bit of the capacitive effects between base and emitter of that BJT.
Also, note that there's very different regulator architectures, some able to even pull down the output voltage if it is too high.
Then again, two regulator in parallel will never be exactly identical, and can oscillate, which the 10 mΩ in series with the output combat – obviously to the detriment of regulation quality.
There's plenty of exceptions, but in general, if you're carrying enough current that "use a slightly larger linear regulator" isn't an option and you need to do such tricks as parallelizing linear regulators or augmenting them with pass transistors, then your first reaction should be that a linear regulator might not be what you need. With modern buck-boost controller ICs, you might at the same circuitry complexity, achieve higher current at acceptable noise – and if the noise isn't acceptable, you can still consider using a much smaller-dropout LDO, as the thermal limits on that won't matter as much, since a smaller voltage drop means proportionally less heat.

Just some observations.
As explained on page 11 of the datasheet, adding the 10mΩ resistors does affect regulation, because feedback is still taken from the IC output (inside the IC), not the overall output.
With two regulators paralleled to supply 1A each, you can expect overall output to fall by \$1A \times 10m\Omega=10mV\$. That's 1% additional error, which may be a deal breaker for you.
The pass-transistor arrangement does not suffer from this, because it's outside of the feedback loop. It also has the benefit of providing (potentially) much more than 2A, though you'll need to take care with power dissipation of course.
The paralleled LT3080 solution does have merit, though. Linear regulators (particularly low-dropout ones) struggle to remain stable with highly capacitive loads, but the 10mΩ ballast will help with that. The datasheet doesn't talk about load capacitance, only stating a mandatory minimum, so I can't say how important an issue this is.

I'm not a big fan of paralleling linear regulators for reasons others have noted. I've built variable supplies with LM317/337s using (by)pass transistors, but these are unsatisfying because you have to mind things like current/temperature sensing. Mine have been kinda of noisy/unstable too, requiring chasing down gremlins.
For a precision, high-current, low-ripple, low-noise, single-regulator supply, I suggest looking at the LM723, an antique that has been a linear supply workhorse for decades. This chip looks externally like an op amp with a small pass transistor, and a very stable on-board voltage reference provided by a buried zener. Since all the terminals for these elements are exposed, it really presents you with a "kit" upon which you can build almost any supply you can imagine. (The chip has a transistor with its collector tied to the base drive of the internal pass, and its base/emitter uncommitted, which can be used to pull down the output--a crude platform upon which to build a current limiter.)
There is a learning curve with this chip, to be sure, and it is quite unforgiving if you overload the b-c or c-e junctions of the onboard pass element (which is really only suitable to drive the driver of your really big pass). You have to design/build your own over-temperature/over-current circuitry. My projects with this have proven remarkably quiet, stable and durable.
Once you have this gem in your toolkit, your answer will always be "single regulator, multiple element pass" and your lovingly-crafted result will knock the pants off everything else.
